# Change partial string on a field

Tags: mysql

I have a field "my_data" with strings like these :

```
XX-12-XXXX
12-XX-2000
XX-XX-2000
XX-XX-XXXX
```

and I'd like to change every XX and XXXX with, respectively, 00 and 0000

How can I do it with a MySql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET my_data = REPLACE(my_date, 'XX', '00')
```

Note:

I am using `XX` as this will also replace `XXXX`, but not single occurrences of `X`.

Answer (score 1):

You cam use [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
UPDATE table
   SET my_data = REPLACE(my_data, 'X', '0');

SELECT REPLACE(my_data, 'X', '0') AS myData
  FROM table;
```